# Pymongo Error in PyCharm debugger only

Tags: django, debugging, pycharm, pymongo

I am seeing a very weired error while debugging my code in PyCharm. The offending lines that cause the exception are

```
a = db.links.list_indexes()
```

or the following:

```
db.links.create_index("created", expireAfterSeconds=settings.EXPIRY_PERIOD, background=True)
```

My code runs normally inside PyCharm if I simply do `run tests`, while trying to debug it causes the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_detail_view (sharescreening.tests.TestIndex)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sharescreening/tests.py", line 53, in test_detail_view
    response = self.client.get('/')
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 500, in get
    **extra)
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 303, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 379, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 466, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 119, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 365, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 401, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 395, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "sharescreening/urls.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .views import put_links, index, get_shares, ShowDetails
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "sharescreening/views.py", line 22, in <module>
    a = db.links.list_indexes()
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1269, in list_indexes
    with self._socket_for_primary_reads() as (sock_info, slave_ok):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 699, in _socket_for_reads
    with self._get_socket(read_preference) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 663, in _get_socket
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 121, in select_server
    address))
  File "/home/oznt/.virtualenvs/screenshares/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 97, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No servers found yet

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 32.173s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I have no clue why the tests pass in the command line, and in simple running mode but not in debug mode. Can someone shed some light on this problem here?

Comment: This might be more of a question you need to raise with Jetbrains

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was really a problem with the combination or using `gevent` with the debugger.
If you this problem, it is resolved by upgrading your pycharm version to 2006.1.
More details can be found in the [issue in PYCharm tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18896)